# Data center equipment vendors?

Tags: datacenter, server-room

I'm wondering where people purchase their data center / server room components from. In particular, I'm looking to install an Emergency Power Off switch in our server room and have been looking for a supplier that sells those kinds of components, but have not been meeting much success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not necessarily just for data centers... Those switches are used in many industry's.  Call your electrician, they should be able to help you.  I know APC has them for their InfraStruXure products.

Comment: Installing them is also non trivial as you have to get them on your main supply into the room.

Comment: You're right, we really should be getting the electrician to do this for us.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.stayonline.com/ has some cool datacenter stuff..

Answer (score 0):

Your electrician will probably want to help you select one that's appropriate for your environment, just like you would prefer that a client or business ask you before they purchase a whole load of servers or rack hardware. Bonus: The electrician will have wholesale pricing that is not available to you, so the total cost will probably be lower.

For other purposes, we mostly use APC or find a local reseller. The local resellers usually can get better pricing than going through the manufacturer.